# Set new column from datetime on dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to set a new column(Day of year & Hour)
My date time consist of date and hour, i tried to split it up by using

```
data['dayofyear'] = data['Date'].dt.dayofyear
```

and

```
df['Various', 'Day'] = df.index.dayofyear
df['Various', 'Hour'] = df.index.hour
```

but it is always returning error, im not sure how i can split this up and get it to a new column.

[image]

Comment: What is error here?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is there is no `DatetimeIndex`, so use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) first and then assign to new columns names:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['Day'] = df.index.dayofyear
df['Hour'] = df.index.hour
```

Or use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.assign(Day = df.index.dayofyear, Hour = df.index.hour)
```